# Background image not loading on web

Tags: html, css, web

I have a website where it doesn't load the background images; however, it does load when I run it on my local host. Its only when I upload it to the web where it doesn't load. Not sure where the problem might be.

Comment: first of all welcome to SO. to get the best answer for your questions, just read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add ur issue's code to your post so we can help

Comment: Give us your code,it's  probably because your image path it's not the same as in your PC.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost 100% in your image path.

I can't really help you untill I see the code, but one thing you can try is to add `/` in front of the folder and file names.

For example, if your image path on localhost is `images/myImage.jpg`, try to replace it with `/images/myImage.jpg` and see if it changes !